# Shortening numbers in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a document that has numbers such as

```
4100.0
4201.0
4300.1
```

but I need them in the format of

```
410
420
430
```

I'm trying to write a global excel macro in VBA (first time using VBA) to do this but seem to have hit a road block. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ItemNum As Range

For Each num In ItemNum


End Sub
```

ItemNum.NumberFormat ("000")

I have figured out how to walk through a defined range and I found range.numberformat but that only gets rid of the decimals, not the final 0 / 1. I also can't figure out how to make it accessible to all of my spreadsheets.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: So you want to remove the last digit from a number, but only if the last digit is either 0 or 1, right?. Divide it by 10 and round it off. I hope that works

Comment: You can use `Str(num)` to ge the number as a string. Then yiu can use character manipulation such as `mid` to keep only what you want, then put it back.

Comment: If I use your 'Str(num)' method, how do I get it back into its original cell?

Comment: You could do this with a formula using =TEXT(<string>,"000")